# Integer to float

Tags: haskell, floating-point, integer

This code works:

```
posToXY :: Float -> Float -> Integer
posToXY a b = do
        let y = a / b
        round y
```

But this doesn't work:

```
posToXY :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
posToXY a b = do
        let y = a / b
        round y
```

I understand that operation '/' doesn't define for Integer type, but I don't know how to fix code to work with Integer parameters.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397210/haskell-converting-float-to-int

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275193/whats-the-right-way-to-divide-two-int-values-to-obtain-a-float

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to perform fractional division, you can convert from any `Integral` type using `fromIntegral`, or `fromInteger` to convert only from `Integer` specifically.

There are similar functions relating to other numeric type classes: `toRational`, `fromRational`, `realToFrac`, etc. And of course you can convert fractional types back to integral types using `round`, `floor`, `ceiling`, or such.

And finally, on the off chance that you actually wanted *integer* division, instead of fractional division with rounding afterwards, there's the `div` and `quot` functions (depending on what truncation behavior you want).

Also, you probably should write your function as something like `posToXY a b = round $ a / b`. The unnecessary `do` and multiple lines makes it harder to read.

Comment: `posToXY a b = round $ a / b` -- in this case, I personally prefer parentheses for readability - it saves having to think (even for just a split second) about operator precedence, and it just looks more like the mathematical expression it represents.

Comment: @mokus: Yeah, I agree. I only used `($)` here out of habit, I likely would've used parentheses in actual code.

Comment: @C.A.McCann *`you probably should write your function as...`* -- are you suggesting to better merge the two functions into one?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `fromIntegral` to convert any Integral type into any Num type. So:

```
let y = fromIntegral a / fromIntegral b
```

Answer (score 7):

Your code could easily be simplified to

```
posToXY :: Float -> Float -> Integer
posToXY a b = round (a / b)
```

Then

```
posToXY :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
posToXY a b = round (fromIntegral a / fromIntegral b)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want integer division, you can use `div`.

```
posToXY :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
posToXY = div
```

Note this isn't quite the same as rounding a floating-point division, because `div` always rounds down.

For a more general type signature, you can do this instead

```
p :: (Real a, Real a1, Integral b) => a -> a1 -> b
posToXY a b = round (realToFrac a / realToFrac b)
```