# Haskell int to float and char to float

Tags: haskell, floating-point, int

Is there a function in haskell which converts from int to float, and from char to float?

I know that there is a function that converts from char to int and int to char.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968265/integer-to-float

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions like this can be answered with [hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Char+-%3E+Int).

For example, Hoogle for "Char -> Int" and the first function listed will do it (`ord`, mentioned in other answers, is the second result):

```
digitToInt :: Char -> Int
```

Though your need for a function [:: Char -> Float](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Char+-%3E+Float) does mandate using `read` (third result down) or a combination of digitToInt and a function [:: Int -> Float](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+Float):

```
digitToFloat = toEnum . digitToInt
```

Comment: I knew there was a function like digitToInt, but I was too lazy to look for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

`fromIntegral` will convert from Int to Float.

For Char to Float, it depends.  If you want to get the ASCII value of a Char (ignoring Unicode for now), use Data.Char.ord:

```
Prelude Data.Char> fromIntegral (ord '2') :: Float
50.0
```

If you want to read the digit of a Char, i.e. `'2'` becomes the value `2`, you can do this:

```
char2float :: Char -> Float
char2float n = fromInteger (read [n])

Prelude Data.Char> char2float '2'
2.0
```

If you're going to do a lot of this, you might consider using an actual parsing library to get actual error handling.

Comment: You can just do `char2float n = read [n]`. No need for `fromInteger`.

Answer (score 2):

did you try:

```
intToFloat :: Int -> Float
intToFloat n = fromInteger (toInteger n)
```

[Additionally see here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Converting_numbers)

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you can use Read typeclass for these purposes. And it means you can convert some basic types to some other basic types.

Converting from Int to a Float:

```
Prelude> 1::Float
1.0
```

**BUT** I don't know which means converting from char to Float - maybe [Char] to Float or String to Float? Anyway:

```
Prelude> read("1")::Float
1.0
```

Check out this link: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html